# uikit, emberjs, and the {

Tags: javascript, ember.js, uikit, handlebars.js

I am trying to use UIKit for the theme of an EmberJS project. I am finding that the attributes for UIKit that require a { and } don't seem to work. For example a button with a drop down requires:

```
data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}"
```

but doesn't work when rendered in EmberJS. If I take the `{mode:'click'}` off, it works fine as a hover so I know JS is working.

Do I need to escape it? Thanks and let me know!

Comment: Its probably not an ember problem. I think maybe uikit does not catch embers changes on the DOM?

Comment: Is there any way to make it work with the attributes? If I remove the {mode:'click'} attribute, the uikit button with hover works fine but I want it to be a click. I think its more a handlebars issue than an ember one but its packed into Ember.

Comment: Can you provide a non working sample? Because I checked it in a twiddle and HTMLBars *does* pass the `{`!

Comment: <div class="uk-button-dropdown" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}">
<a href="#" class="top_menu_toggle"><i class="material-icons md-24" style="color:#FFF;">&#xE8F0;</i></a>
<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-width-3" style="margin-top: 14px;">
<div class="uk-grid uk-dropdown-grid">Things here</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: I mean something like a git project. How did you include uikit, what ember version, etc.